# Vega-Embed giving build error Cannot find name 'Extract' and 'Exclude'

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I created angular 6 application(Using  node). In this application I used vega-embed. It is giving me compilation error.

**import embed from 'vega-embed';
I also changed code in util.d.ts import stableStringify = require('json-stable-stringify') but giving following error**

**ERROR in node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/util.d.ts(58,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Extract'.
node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/util.d.ts(73,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.**

Please suggest.

Comment: What TypeScript version do you use?

Comment: This is an error with Typescript. Please update.